# R : extract rows which belong to the same group

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to print all rows belonging to the same group on the console.
However, skip records that belong to a unique group.

```
  id1 id2 name dob sex group
1   1   2    0   1   0       1
2   1   3    0   0   1       2
3   1   4    1   1   1       2
4   2   3    0   0   0       3
5   2   4    0   1   0       4
6   3   4    0   0   1       4
4   2   3    0   0   0       4
5   2   4    0   1   0       5
6   3   4    0   0   1       6
```

Result :

```
  id1 id2 name dob sex group
2   1   3    0   0   1       2
3   1   4    1   1   1       2

  id1 id2 name dob sex group
5   2   4    0   1   0       4
6   3   4    0   0   1       4
4   2   3    0   0   0       4
```

The below works great to get the non-unique ones, but I need a for loop for this to print to the screen.

```
library(dplyr)
dfC %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(n()>1)
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop?

Comment: because i'm printing to the screen, after every group
I'm using a readline to get user validation for each group

Comment: You could use the `split` function to break apart the result you already have by `group` - `dfC %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>% 
  split(., .$group)` - would that be sufficient?

Comment: `df2 = split(df1, df1$group); for(x in df2[sapply(df2, NROW) > 1]) print(x);`

Comment: @thelatemail this is great! how would you add readline("Add this group?") to get user validation? i tried adding it simply, it returns unused argument

Comment: perfect @d.b if you paste it in answer i'll accept yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_walk` with `print`

```
library(dplyr)
dfC %>% 
  group_by(grp = group) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  group_walk(print)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#    id1   id2  name   dob   sex group
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     3     0     0     1     2
#2     1     4     1     1     1     2
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#    id1   id2  name   dob   sex group
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     2     4     0     1     0     4
#2     3     4     0     0     1     4
#3     2     3     0     0     0     4
```

#### data

```
dfC <- structure(list(id1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L), id2 = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L), name = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), dob = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), 
    sex = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), group = c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun
any way to keep the group information?

Comment: @Yeshyyy  The `group` column is already present if you check the output